# Android: Display custom keyboard then hide soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I have two `EditText` in my layout, and another layout that contains a custom designed keyboard using `ImageButtons`. Using these two layouts, I want to:

1. When the `EditText` is clicked/touched, hide the default keyboard.
2. Display the custom keyboard (like a replacement to the default keyboard).
3. Hide the keyboard after clicking back/return key.

I was able to hide the default keyboard by setting the `InputType` of the two `EditText` to NULL. However, it means that the cursor will no longer be visible when `EditText` is focused. This is part of the specifications of the project.

How do I best approach this problem? What could be a best solution?

**Edit:** Project specifications were changed. However, I would still love to have the solution or approach to this problem / issue. Thank you very much.